# JPA: bulk save child and parent entities at the same time

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, orm

I'm migrating from classic Spring 4.3.2 + Hibernate (HQL) to Spring Boot 1.4.1 + Hibernate (JPA) + HikariCP connection pool and have trouble with bulk insert. I need to save large lists from 1000 to 527 000 elements. 
When I'm saving batch of only one entity, without any dependencies (e.g: 5000 elements of `Category` class), everything is ok. 
However, if I try to save both the child and parent entities (`Website` with just set `Category` for it), I get the exception: `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.entities.Category` 
But **when the list size is less then** `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size`**, everything is ok** too!!! Both entities are saved properly, the parent and the child. That seems really strange!

 I've googled enough, searched at StackOverflow, but could't find solution to specifically my problem. I've tried to replace the connection pool to Apache DBCP or even didn't include one at all), changed Hibernate performance settings, replaced PostgreSQL db to H2 - but no result. 
 
**Where could be the error? 

Is it possible to do in JPA what I want?** Or I should save entities separately (firstly, the parent and then the child)? Another way is to exclude `flush()` and `clear()` from my program, but it's not good for performance!

 Hope for help. Here are the details.
That's how I'm trying to save entities:

```
    @Repository("experimentDao")
    @Transactional
    public class Dao {
        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager entityManager;

        @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}")
        private int batchSize;

        public <T extends Entity> void bulkSave(Collection<T> entities) {
            int i = 0;
            for (Entity entity : entities) {
                persistOrMerge(entity);
                i++;
                if (i % batchSize == 0) {
                    // Flush a batch of inserts and release memory.
                    entityManager.flush();
                    entityManager.clear();
                }
            }
        }

    private <T extends Entity> void persistOrMerge(T entity) {
        if (entity.getId() == null) {
            entityManager.persist(entity);
        } else {
            entityManager.merge(entity);
        }
    }
 }
```

(the example was found at: http://frightanic.com/software-development/jpa-batch-inserts/). 
And I'm getting following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:803) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:771) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:24) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.entities.Category; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.entities.Category
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:299) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.Dao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$79470367.bulkSave(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.DemoApplication.insertWebsites(DemoApplication.java:44) [classes/:na]
    at com.example.DemoApplication.run(DemoApplication.java:30) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.entities.Category
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:765) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:758) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:80) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:775) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.Dao.persistOrMerge(Dao.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.Dao.bulkSave(Dao.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.Dao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2ada4001.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

`Website` and `Category` entities have one-to-one relation, `Category` is a parent. And I have abstract superclass, as well, which shouln't be persisted:

```
public abstract class Entity {
    public abstract Long getId();
}

@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "websites")
public class Website extends Entity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "website_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "url", unique = true)
    private String url;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id")
    private Category category;
    // getters and setters, toString
}

@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category extends Entity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "category_name", unique = true)
    private String categoryName;
    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Now I wanna save 5000 `Website`s belonging to the same `Category`. Here's how I do bulk insert:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private Dao dao;

    @Autowired
    public void setDao(Dao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        insertWebsites();
    }

    private void insertWebsites() {
        List<Website> entities = new ArrayList<>(5000);
        Category category = new Category();
        category.setCategoryName("my category");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
            Website website = new Website();
            website.setUrl("http://example.com" + i);
            website.setCategory(category);
            entities.add(website);
        }
        dao.bulkSave(entities);
    }
}
```

Settings and parameters:

 (application.properties)

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spring_web
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = postgresql
spring.datasource.type = com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource

# Hibernate
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.max_fetch_depth = 3
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size = 30
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 30
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache = false
```

(pom.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>runtime</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Sorry for being verbose, I tried to give all the details. Looking forward to getting any help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be made clear once you follow the execution:

- A single category gets created
- `batch_size` websites are created and persisted; they all point to the single category created above

  - As soon as the first website is persisted, the category is persisted too because of the cascade in the relationship
- Since all `batch_size` websites and the category are persisted, they live within the persistence context. But as soon as you call `entityManager.clear()` they are thrown away from the persistence context (to free memory). **Thus the single category becomes detached (i.e. removed from the persistence context) and you get the exception.** The example in the site you mention does not persist through a relation, that is why it works.

I do not believe `bulkSave()` can work in such a generic way given the relationship. If you want to bulk insert websites, do something along the lines:

```
@Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}")
private int batchSize;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em; // you will need the EntityManager

private void insertWebsites() {
    Category category = new Category();
    category.setCategoryName("my category");
    // persist it separately to keep the id for later
    em.persist(category);
    Long categoryId = category.getId();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5000; i++) {
        Website website = new Website();
        website.setUrl("http://example.com" + i);
        website.setCategory(category);
        if (i % batchSize == 0) {
            em.flush();
            em.clear();
            // get an attached reference to the category (you know
            // that it exists) without querying the database again
            category = em.getReference(Category.class, categoryId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've followed your instructions, and everything is fine.
But when I try to add one more entity `Blacklist` to a cascade, `detached entity passed to persist` occurs again. Please, see my example code at pastebin: [link](http://pastebin.com/Y26xjS7A)